How do I use an index (barrel) file without breaking react-refresh?
Say I have a module foo and it's got some stuff in it:
// foo/index.js
export { default as SomeComponent } from './SomeComponent'
export { someUtil } from './utilities'
export const SOME_CONSTANT = 42

Now I can import everything I need directly from foo without seeing implementation details about which file something is in:
// bar.js
import { SomeComponent, someUtil, SOME_CONSTANT } from 'foo'

So I got that going for me, which is nice.
But now I get eslint errors from my react-refresh/only-export-components rule warning me that "Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components". Ok, it's true that index.js exports both components and other stuff (functions, constants). Does this rule mean that my foo module/package basically can't effectively use an index file -- i.e., that either the components or the other stuff will have to be imported directly from wherever they are used?
// bar.js
import { SOME_CONSTANT, someUtil } from 'foo'
import SomeComponent from 'foo/SomeComponent'

Am I understanding the react-refresh rule here? If so, what's the recommended pattern for module-level exports that doesn't break it?

Barrel files are often considered an anti-pattern… can you [edit] the question to clarify the reason for using one?

@jsejcksn I hadn't heard that before ... after some research, I'm not married to barrel files but also not entirely convinced by the arguments against them. So sure, just not using barrel files would solve my problem and 'll probably end up doing that. But in the meantime I'm still interested in answers to this question.

React Fast refresh needs a clear way to detect which files are for components. To fix this, separate your exports into two files -

foo/components.js file - for components export
foo/index.js - for utilities and constants export.

This approach follows the react-refresh/only-export-components rule and allows for project scaling. It keeps things clean and avoid headaches down the road.
// foo/components.js
export { default as SomeComponent } from './SomeComponent';

.
// foo/index.js
export { someUtil } from './utilities';
export const SOME_CONSTANT = 42;

To import:
import { SomeComponent } from 'foo/components';
import { someUtil, SOME_CONSTANT } from 'foo';

